$\frac{p}{p-1}$ in base $p$
I am tasked with writing the fraction $z=\frac{p}{p-1}$ in base $p$. I thought of writing $z$ as follows: $$\frac{p}{p-1}<1\Rightarrow z=1+x$$
where $x\in(0,1)$. So I just need to to write $x$ in base $p$, but I am not sure how to go about doing that. I would appreciate any help.
Edit: Thanks for the hints! Regarding the geometric series, I rewrote $$\frac{p}{p-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}p^{1-n}=p^1+p^0+p^{-1}+\ldots$$
This agrees for example with $\frac{10}{9}=1,11111\ldots$

$p/(p-1)$ is greater than 1 if $p$ is greater than 1. Have you tried $10/(10-1)$ in base 10 or $4/(4-1)$ in base 4?

Hint : Think of how you convert fractions to binary!

Hint: $\frac{p}{p-1} = \frac{1}{1-\tfrac{1}{p}}$. If you know the geometric series for $\frac{1}{1-x}$, then you've got it.
